# How do I force form submit with Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Wish you all a happy 2015!

I have a simple contact us php form. I am validating it with parsley.js. The validation works fine but I am receiving a lot of spam mails.

I believe if I can force the form to be submitted only if Jquery is enabled, then it should solve my problem (right?).

I'm not an expert with PhP/ Jquery and any help will be appreciated.

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php

// Define Variables i.e. name tag, as per form and set to empty
$contact_name = $contact_email = $contact_phone = $contact_message = "";

// Sanitize data and use friendly names
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $name = test_input($_POST["contact_name"]);
  $email = test_input($_POST["contact_email"]);
  $phone = test_input($_POST["contact_phone"]);
  $message = test_input($_POST["contact_message"]);
}
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

// Set values
$to = 'info@foryourservice.in';
$subject = 'New Message from Website';
$headers = 'From: info@domainname.com' . "\r\n" .
   'Reply-To: info@domainname.com' . "\r\n" .
   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// Set Email content           
$emailcontent = "A new message has been submitted from the website.
\n
Name : $name
Email : $email
Phone : $phone
Message : $message";

// Mail function
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$emailcontent,$headers);

if($send_contact){
header('Location: index.php#contactusform');
}
else {
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('We encountered an ERROR! Please go back and try again.');</script>";
}

?>
```

Here is my HTML ( Im using Twitter Bootstrap)

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="contactusform.php" id="contactusform" data-parsley-validate>
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: -5px">
    <label for="input1"></label>
    <input type="text" name="contact_name" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Name*" required data-parsley-required-message="Please enter your name">
    </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: -5px">
    <label for="input2"></label>
    <input type="email" name="contact_email" class="form-control" id="input2" placeholder="Email Address*" data-parsley-trigger="change" required data-parsley-required-message="Please enter a valid Email address">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: -5px">
    <label for="input3"></label>
    <input type="tel" name="contact_phone" class="form-control" id="input3" placeholder="Phone Number*" required data-parsley-type="digits" data-parsley-minlength="10" data-parsley-maxlength="10" data-parsley-required-message="Please enter a 10 digit number">
        </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" id="contactbutton" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #A8B645; border-color: transparent">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input4"></label>
    <textarea name="contact_message" class="form-control" rows="7" id="input4" placeholder="Message*" required required data-parsley-required-message="Say something!"></textarea>
        </div>
</div>
</form>
```

This is what the Spam Email looks like :

A new message has been submitted from the website.

Name : &#12362;&#36023;&#12356;&#24471;&#12450;&#12490;&#12473;&#12452; &#12511;&#12525;&#12540;&#12489;&#22823;&#22771;&#12426;&#20986;&#12375;&#12521;&#12531;&#12461;&#12531;&#12464;
Email : rsilau@gmail.com
Phone : &#12362;&#36023;&#12356;&#24471;&#12450;&#12490;&#12473;&#12452; &#12511;&#12525;&#12540;&#12489;&#22823;&#22771;&#12426;&#20986;&#12375;&#12521;&#12531;&#12461;&#12531;&#12464;
Message : Shoppers takes the boast on bag
&#12362;&#36023;&#12356;&#24471;&#12450;&#12490;&#12473;&#12452; &#12511;&#12525;&#12540;&#12489;&#22823;&#22771;&#12426;&#20986;&#12375;&#12521;&#12531;&#12461;&#12531;&#12464; http://www.frkapaun.org/dyqfmnwg/ysl-annasuixmraAekm.asp

Comment: Always exit script after header with location.

Comment: you might need to take stronger measures, read this for instance: http://www.clfsrpm.net/csrf/ and also a Captcha is an easy way to go too: http://www.w3schools.in/php/captcha. but there are also special tools made for spam control and stuff, search for theme your problem wouldn't solve with this.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden field to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" id="botcheck" name="botcheck" />
```

Then with jQuery set the value to `1`:

```
$("#botcheck").val("1");
```

Then server-side check the value of `$_POST["botcheck"]`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this now. Seems it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if your form is submitted using ajax:

```
 if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
  //Process form here
 }
```

[For further explanation](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but Im not using Ajax.